# My SharePoint Online Alert is sending an alert based on anything in the list, not the filtered items

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, filter, alert

I have a List with a one filtered view.  I set an Alert on the list, hoping that the email would only show the items that pass the filter.  But everything in the List is showing up in the email.

- Is this normal?
- Is there a way to make the Alert only show the items that pass the View filter?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's normal, the Alerts works on all items within the list regardless the filter settings!

[image]

**Is there a way to make the Alert only show the items that pass the View filter?**

As OOTB, Unfortunately, **No**

---

**Workaround**

You can create a workflow that sends an email alert with IF condition that simulates your filter settings

**For example:** you have configured the filter with a specific column equal to a specific value, so in your workflow drop If condition with this rule then sends email alert in case the condition true!